# Skull's bones or skull bones?

Tags: possessives

What is the correct option of these following two?

> skull'**s** bones

or

> skull bones

Please, explain me the answer, because it's something that I have often.

The context: 
"22 skull bones (or skull's bone) + 34 vertebrae are equal to 56 bones."

Answer (score 4):

In most cases you would say **skull bones**, since that is a particular category of bones, just as their are foot bones, arm bones, or leg bones.  For example:

> There are 22 **skull bones**.
>   The occipital bone is the **skull bone** found on the lower back of the head.

There are some limited cases in which you might use the possessive though.  If you were describing the skull in general and wanted to comment on its bones, you might say something like:

> The **skull's bones** begin as a collection of plates that fuse together as a person matures.

Perhaps more likely in this case would be a possessive phrase that is a bit old fashioned in most other circumstances.

> The **bones of the skull** begin as ...